# SyntaxError: missing ; before statement while concate in javascript loop

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I used contact in php like this

```
$location_space     = '';
$location_formation = '';

foreach($location as $formation) {
    $location_formation .= $formation.', ';
    $location_space     .= $formation.'<br />';
}
```

When I wanted to change it into javascript:

```
var location_space      = '';
var location_formation  = '';

for (i = 0; i < new_location.length; i++) {
    var location_space      += new_location[i] + ', ';
    var location_formation  += new_location[i] + '<br />';
}
```

It showed me this error

> Error: SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
>   Line: 311, Column: 32
>   Source Code:  var location_space   += new_location[i] + ', ';

So what is wrong?

Comment: Remove the `var` in the for loop - the variable is already declared outside the loop

Comment: Just to clarify some of the answers: The problem is not the definition itself, it's the definition combined with the *shorthand* concatenation that creates this error. `var location_space = location_space + new_location[i] + ', ';` would work just fine (but of course there is no reason to use `var` here again).

Comment: Who's downvoting all the correct answers without further explanations?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario It is my question too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already defined `location_space` and `location_formation`, so you only need to assign a value to them, not redeclare them inside the `for()` loop:

```
var location_space      = '';
var location_formation  = '';

for (var i = 0; i < new_location.length; i++) 
{
    location_space      += new_location[i] + ', ';
    location_formation  += new_location[i] + '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have already declared the variables before the for loop, so if you remove the `var`s from inside the loop, the string concatenation should work.

Answer (score 0):

You should not define the `location_space` and `location_formation` in the for again.

 Change your code to this:

```
 var location_space      = '';
 var location_formation  = '';
 for(var i = 0; i < new_location.length; i++)
 {
     location_space      += new_location[i] + ', ';
     location_formation  += new_location[i] + '<br />';
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to :

```
for (i = 0; i < new_location.length; i++) {
    location_space      += new_location[i] + ', ';
    location_formation  += new_location[i] + '<br />';
}
```

and try

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace with:

```
var location_space      = '';
var location_formation  = '';

for(i=0; i<new_location.length; i++) {
    location_space      += new_location[i] + ', ';
    location_formation  += new_location[i] + '<br />';
}
```

You're trying to declare location_space and location_formation again and use it like it was declared before "+=".